# cannot load widget plugin in ckeditor bundled in ruby gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I am using rails 3.2 with the ckeditor gem version 4.0.4.  I want to switch to the enhanced image plugin (http://ckeditor.com/addon/image2).  I have downloaded this plugin and the dependent widget and line tiles plugins.  However, I am getting this error when the widget plugin:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getIndex'`

I have loaded the plugin files in application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require underscore
//= require_tree ./frontend
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require lineutils/plugin
//= require widget/plugin
//= require widget/lang/en
//= require image2/plugin
//= require image2/lang/en
//= require doksoft_image_embed/dlg
//= require doksoft_image_embed/plugin
//= require doksoft_image_embed/lang/en
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-slider
//= require bootstrap-select
//= require highcharts
//= require highcharts/draggable-points
//= require main
```

Then in my ckeditor/config.js I added this line

```
  config.extraPlugins = "doksoft_image_embed,image2";
```

which then causes the error.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Does it work without doksoft_image_embed? What is the `Object #<Object>`?